# python dictionary formatting?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to parse xml file from open street map.
this is the entire code I am try to clean my data.
the part I'm looking is in the second level of xml where the address is a nested dict like josn. which I couldn't figure out. and I'm not able to print the top level after I code for second level.

```
def shape_element(element):
    node = {}
    a=[]               
    if element.tag == "node" or element.tag == "way" :
        data=element.attrib
        node["created"]={c:data[c] for c in CREATED}
        a.append(element.get("lat"))
        a.append(element.get("lon"))
        node["pos"]=a
        node["id"]=data["id"]
        node["visible"]=data["visible"]

    if element.tag =="tag":
        for tag in element.iter():
            atb=tag.attrib
            i=atb["k"]

            if re.search(lower_colon,i):
                node["address"]={}
                m=re.search("(?<=addr:)\w+",i)
                k=m.group(0)
                node["address"][k]=atb['v']
        pprint.pprint (node)
def process_map(file_in, pretty = False):
file_out = "{0}.json".format(file_in)
data = []
with codecs.open(file_out, "w") as fo:
    for _, element in ET.iterparse(file_in):
        el = shape_element(element)
        if el:
            data.append(el)
            if pretty:
                fo.write(json.dumps(el, indent=2)+"\n")
            else:
                fo.write(json.dumps(el) + "\n")
return data
```

I'm returning something like this:

```
{'address': {'city': 'Chicago'}}
{'address': {'housenumber': '5157'}}
{'address': {'postcode': '60625'}}
{'address': {'street': 'North Lincoln Ave'}}
```

but I'm expecting something like:

```
"address": {
              "housenumber": "5157",
              "postcode": "60625",
              "street": "North Lincoln Ave"
           }
```

I want my finial result like:

```
{
"id": "2406124091",
"type: "node",
"visible":"true",
"created": {
          "version":"2",
          "changeset":"17206049",
          "timestamp":"2013-08-03T16:43:42Z",
          "user":"linuxUser16",
          "uid":"1219059"
        },
"pos": [41.9757030, -87.6921867],
"address": {
          "housenumber": "5157",
          "postcode": "60625",
          "street": "North Lincoln Ave"
         },
"amenity": "restaurant",
"cuisine": "mexican",
"name": "La Cabana De Don Luis",
"phone": "1 (773)-271-5176"
}
```

Comment: What code have you written to generate that dict?

Comment: i'm parsing a xml file from open street map using element tree.                     `if element.tag =="tag":
        for tag in element.iter():
            atb=tag.attrib
            i=atb["k"]
            
            if re.search(lower_colon,i):
                node["address"]={}
                m=re.search("(?<=addr:)\w+",i)
                k=m.group(0)
                node["address"][k]=atb['v']`

Comment: @KarthikElangovan make the changes in your question :)

Comment: Can you also show where `node` is coming from and where you print the output?

Comment: Try writing `node["address"]={}` below this if statement `if element.tag =="tag":`.